# Rabbi and Priest Debate: דצ"ך עד"ש באח"ב

Tags: sources-mekorot, passover-seder-hagada

Some of the commentators on the Haggada [note](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/2834140/jewish/Maggid-Reciting-the-Haggadah.htm) a story between a rav and a priest where the latter claimed דצ"ך עד"ש באח"ב was a reference to our "heinous crimes" while the rav explained how the acronym meant something completely different. Although I heard something relatively similar at another Seder, the debate seemed to feature different statements as the priest reportedly said something along the lines of:

- דצ"ך - dam tzrichim kulchem
- עד"ש - Akum Damim shfoch
- באח"ב - Ben e-l Chai bemaves

while the Rav responded with another twist on the words most of which I don't remember, but ended with באח"ב - Ben erusin Chayav bemaves.

Are there any sources which bring such a conversation?

Comment: I didn't see that it says commentators on the Chabad site. They wrote that they bring that story from [this book](https://hebrewbooks.org/46037).

Comment: @Harel13 Thank you for linking the Hebrewbook - that's not a commentary on the Haggada?

Comment: I don't know Yiddish, but I thought it was a collection of stories. In any case, it's not organized by the Haggadah but by verses from Tanach that are related to Pesach.